# SSIS XML Source, no output although using inline xsd schema

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an xml file with some data and inline schema attached to it.
If i use it in SSIS (2008 or 2005) xml source component, I get no output to any destination (tried, raw file, flat file, excel, ole db, db destination).

The columns come up just fine, mapping in the following component (e.g. db destination) seems to work, mappings ok.

Then if I run the ssis package, checks are ok, tests are ok, everything in "green", but finally 0 rows written to the destination... ;(

I've researched this quite a bit, there are cases about missing columns, data type conversion, schema issues (I have a valid inline schema) etc.

Here is an example with dummy data, there are 5 other schemas with plenty of more columns..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CompanyNameID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <CompanyNameID>1</CompanyNameID>
        <Name>a</Name>
        <Description />
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
        <CompanyNameID>7</CompanyNameID>
        <Name>b</Name>
        <Description />
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
        <CompanyNameID>6</CompanyNameID>
        <Name>c</Name>
        <Description />
      </Table>
    </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Comment: Please show how to get it work.. ;)

Comment: Any ideas? The component output is "wrote 0 rows", could there be some tricks in the component setup?

Timo.

Comment: Do any records flow through the pipeline but they don't get to the destination or is it the problem no data comes in from the file? What all transformations are you applying to the data after the source read? Anything that could be shunting rows out to the bit bucket? Turn logging on for the data flow and capture onpipelinerowssent That'll show rows flowing between components.

Comment: What components have you got in your control flow and (assuming you're using a data flow) your data flow view?

Comment: What happens if you take the schema into a separate file? Can you try the same without the (encoding="utf-16") part? Excel has troubles parsing the provided XML if the encoding is set to utf-16.